# What is recasting in a sentence?? how do you recast a sentence cannot move forward in access course until I get past this?

Tags: writing

I have failed this section of my course three times and just cant get it into my head, I thought it was rearranging a sentence, or adding context always wrong!!

Please could a kind person write me a clear example of recasting text

This is the actual question alongside text I was provided with to use. You are required to write two examples of each of the following using the text in the article provided (see assessor guidance section below to download the article).
•   Paraphrase
•   Re-sequencing / Re-casting
•   Quotation

You must ensure that the meaning of the original text is conveyed when paraphrasing or re-sequencing.

Quotations and re-sequencing examples must be presented in the appropriate manner.

*edit*I was not told how to recast the sentence, just to 're-cast' it. Which I agree is confusing.The only feedback I get is that I am quoting and that the re-cast needs to be in speech marks, which again, I am not able to relate to after researching online. Here is my example.

**Original -** Education encompasses our lives; it is the foundation of our society.

**Recast** - Education is the foundation of our society it encompasses our lives. –

My second attempt was this - Original Text 
Those who have amassed enough education, steer the path of development and progress for their country. It is these individuals who go ahead and become teachers, scientists, inventors, welfare activists, soldiers, and politicians who work together to form the very backbone of the society.

Recast Text 
An individual is able to steer a path of career development when they have progressed far enough academically. They create the backbone of the society by becoming teachers, scientists, inventors, welfare activists, soldiers, and politicians.

I am able to paraphrase very well, I just do not understand the particular requirements of recasting.

Comment: Surely the test had instructions that went into greater detail than the simple command "Recast this sentence"?

Comment: It sounds like you did recast it, but you recast it incorrectly. We need to know *how* it was supposed to be recast.

Comment: I'm flagging this question for closure as *Unclear*, as there's currently not enough information to enable us to answer it. Gemm45, please [edit] your question to include both the instructions and an example of what you got wrong.

Comment: TRomano - This was the full question You are required to write two examples of each of the following using the text in the article provided (see assessor guidance section below to download the article).
• Paraphrase
• Re-sequencing / Re-casting
• Quotation

You must ensure that the meaning of the original text is conveyed when paraphrasing or re-sequencing. 

Quotations and re-sequencing examples must be presented in the appropriate manner.

Answer (score 1):

**Recasting** depends on what the goal is.

Take a sentence:

> Tom rode the bicycle.

Recast it as passive:

> The bicycle was ridden (by Tom).

Recast it as a question:

> Did Tom ride the bicycle?

Recast it in future tense:

> Tom will ride the bicycle.

and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It has made this much easier now.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final attempt.

Re-sequencing/ Re-casting

**Original -** Education helps to stimulate our minds and mould inquisitive minds into intellectuals.

**Recast -** Mohan, R. (2012), stated - "Education helps to mould inquisitive minds into intellectuals and helps to stimulate our minds."
**Reference -** 
Mohan, R. (2012), “The Importance of Education in Society”, http://merseamusic.blogspot.co.uk

**Original -** Education encompasses our lives; it is the foundation of our society.

**Recast** -Mohan, R. (2012), stated - " Education is the foundation of our society; it encompasses our lives."
**Reference** - Mohan, R. (2012), “The Importance of Education in Society”, http://merseamusic.blogspot.co.uk

Comment: This isn't an answer, and I don't think it's necessary for you to include it on your original question. You have explained your dilemma very well, and the question is now very clear, so well done!

Comment: Upvote retracted, and I rolled back the edit. Good luck on your future studies.